# Symfony2 createFormBuilder

Tags: php, symfony

This is probably easy question but I could not find answer on the official symfony2 documentation page.

This is my form:

> ```
>     $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
>          ->add('myInputField', 'text'))
>          ->add('myAnotherInputFiled', 'date', array(
>              'widget' => 'single_text',
>              'required' => false))
>          ->getForm();
> ```

Question is how to add attribute to the myInputField like "class" or "title"?

I tried "...->add('myInputField', 'text', array('class' => 'CustomClass')..." but I get "the option "class" does not exist.

I need to do it before its outputed in the view.

For any help big thanks!

Comment: With what do you render the form? Are you using twig or php based themes? Do you use some other than the default theme?

Comment: Got the answer below, sorry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add additional attributes using the **attr** option. I noticed it adds the attributes on both the label and the widget, but at least it gets the information through.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
     ->add('myInputField', 'text'))
     ->add('myAnotherInputFiled', 'date', array(
         'widget' => 'single_text',
         'required' => false,
         'attr' => array(
             'class' => 'CustomClass',
         ),
     ))
     ->getForm();
```